# How to call a class method using Optional

Tags: java, option-type

I am trying to call a private method from Optional.ispresent(callmethod) but getting compilation error.

Basically this is the condition I am checking for and if it satisfies, then call the private method.

```
final OrderLines orderLines = readFromMockFile();

if (null != searchCriteria.getSearch() && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(searchCriteria.getSearch().getValue())) {

     applySearchConfig(searchCriteria.getSearch(), orderLines);

}
```

To avoid null checks , I rewrote this code using Optional

```
Optional.ofNullable(searchCriteria.getSearch())
   .map(x -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(x.getValue()))
   .ifPresent(applySearchConfig(searchCriteria.getSearch()));
```

But I am getting compilation error *The method ifPresent(Consumer) in the type Optional is not applicable for the arguments (OrderLines)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifPresent()` accepts a `Consumer` as parameter.
But you pass to it the method you want to invoke (that I suppose doesn't return a `Consumer`):

```
.ifPresent(applySearchConfig(searchCriteria.getSearch()));
```

Besides, you used `map` instead of `filter` here :

```
.map(x -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(x.getValue()))
```

So you map the result of the check to `true` or `false`.
You don't want that either as this makes the value present whatever its result (`true` or `false`).

Try that :

```
Optional.ofNullable(searchCriteria.getSearch())
   .filter(x -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(x.getValue()))
   .ifPresent(x -> applySearchConfig(x, orderLines));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Didn't occur to me to use Filter !!